# How to write special characters such as inferior signs in blogger?

Tags: html, r, blogger

I use [blogger](http://paulremote.blogspot.fr/2014/04/r-commands.html) to post about various coding experiments and I have annoying problems when using special characters such as the inferior sign.
When I enter this:

```
x<1
```

I get this in the view mode

```
x<1 br="">
```

And this in the editing mode

```
x<1 data-blogger-escaped-br="">
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using
`&#60;` or `&lt;` for the symbol?

Comment: Thanks @Adam, both work but they are a pain to use when copy-pasting several lines of code into Blogger.

Comment: @Paul4forest that's using html entities on the web for you.  You may be able to write some javascript to do it automatically, similar to this:  
http://www.spicytweaks.com/2013/12/how-to-add-html-encoderparser-tool-in.html  
You'd want to add a regular expression to check for only unclosed < and > symbols, so you don't replace actual markup.